# Xcode don't show stack of error

Tags: xcode

Hi im working with Xcode and swift3.

When I run the app, crash but in Xcode don't show me error:

[image]

If I want found the line when error is present,  what i can do

Answer (score 1):

Apple refers to this as an "Abnormal Exit" of your application. From the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html):

> **Abnormal Exit [EXC_CRASH // SIGABRT]** - The process exited abnormally. The most common causes of crashes with this exception type are uncaught Objective-C/C++ exceptions and calls to abort().
>
> App Extensions will be terminated with this exception type if they take too much time to initialize (a watchdog termination). If an extension is killed due to a hang at launch, the Exception Subtype of the generated crash report will be LAUNCH_HANG. Because extensions do not have a main function, any time spent initializing occurs within static constructors and +load methods present in your extension and dependent libraries. You should defer as much of this work as possible.

I have found that this is caused because of passing `Foundation` or `UIKit` an invalid parameter to do it's work under the hood. If I were you I would look into what could possibly be causing this by setting [breakpoints](http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode) where your application is having this crash and narrow down a culprit.